# Copy multiple items to clipboard in Python

Tags: python, clipboard, copy-paste

I tried using pyperclip but it only copies the last value. This is what I have right now

```
import pyperclip

array = ["a" , "b", "c"]

for x in array:
    pyperclip.copy(x)
```

This only copies "c", whereas I want to copy all 3 values

I know I can join the values together and copy, but then it's all in one entry [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXkek.png)

I want it to be [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYmq0.png) instead (order doesn't really matter)

Comment: If you insert a `time.sleep(1)` in your loop then each entry gets added. I suspect there's some logic in Windows to prevent spamming of the clipboard history where a second copy within a certain time period will overwrite the last copy.

Comment: If you don't mind importing pandas, you could try `pd.DataFrame(array).to_clipboard(header=False, index=False)`.